# Does a MBP with is a lower base frequency CPU  - but same generation - draw less power?

Tags: cpu, power, cpufreq

When purchasing a new MBP I want to optimize it for mobile usage.

There are different quad-core i7 processor available for the 15'' MBP. See the list [here](http://ark.intel.com/compare/53476,53474,53470). While they have different features, all of them have the same maximum thermal design power:

[image]

- How does their power drain compare at their **base frequencies**?
- Will a processor of the same generation, but lower base frequency, draw less power?

Comment: Modern processors spend most of their time not working. E.g. when you're using a word processor, up to 90% of the time between keypresses your CPU will be asleep. Faster processors will spend more of their time asleep. Spending 90% of the time at 0 Hz makes the notion of a "base frequency" quite meaningless.

Comment: I don't understand. I've never noticed my CPU not working. I have a CPU monitor currently running and it's never 100% idle.

Comment: The feature is intentionally not noticeable. The CPU is not in a "deep" sleep, so it can respond immediately. As you note, your CPU is often 90% idle - that's the average over 1000 milliseconds. In practice, this means it's 100% idle during 900 milliseconds, and 100% busy during the other 100 ms.

Comment: Ah ok. So would you assume, that the high-frequncy processors would consumer less power overall because they sleep more?

Comment: No, because this is precisely offset by their higher power draw when they're not asleep. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, within the same family, CPUs draw almost the same amount of energy *per instruction*. Faster CPU's can execute more instructions per second, so they *can* draw more power *if* they're fully loaded.

Comment: This makes sense, because the architecture of the CPU determines the power consumption of an instruction, right? I'm close to accepting this. I would just like some literature for confirming your first sentence.

Comment: For a given architecture, the transistors used by a ssingle instruction are fixed. [This paper](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=energy%20transistor%20switch%20joule%20-thief&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.87.15%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=6TtGT-PcHM-OswbjkKSFCw&usg=AFQjCNF0Xhaq7GkHpgw0u3vo-9aouDuD1w) shows that the energy used per transistor per operation is pretty much constant, therefore the total energy use per instruction is fixed too. (BTW PC CPU's are classified as high-performace in that paper)

Comment: Great @MSalters! Thank you very much for your help :)